# Which function to call while inheriting a contract?

Tags: erc-721, solidity-0.8.x, erc

I was learning about Access Control in Solidity . I found OpenZeppelin's AccessControl.sol in which these 2 functions were available . I have a doubt as to which function to call in the inheriting contract ? ( the public one or the internal one and why? )

```
abstract contract AccessControl is Context, IAccessControl, ERC165 {
           function grantRole(bytes32 role, address account) public virtual override onlyRole(getRoleAdmin(role)) {
                _grantRole(role, account);
            }
            function _grantRole(bytes32 role, address account) internal virtual {
                if (!hasRole(role, account)) {
                    _roles[role].members[account] = true;
                    emit RoleGranted(role, account, _msgSender());
                }
            }
    }

contract MyAccessControl is ERC721,AccessControl {

    function mint(address to , uint256 tokenId) external {
        _setRoleAdmin(MINTER,DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE); // set DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE as Admin role for MINTER
        _grantRole(MINTER,msg.sender); // granted MINTER role to the person calling this function
        _mint(to,tokenId);
    }

    function burnToken(uint256 tokenId) external  { 
        require(hasRole(MINTER, msg.sender) || _ownerOf(tokenId) == msg.sender,"neither you are minter of token nor you are the owner");
        _burn(tokenId);
    }

}
```

Can the _grantRole() function be called inside MyAccessControl ? Or should it be replaced with grantRole() ?
Note : grantRole() is public function and _grantRole() is internal function. All the functions starting with underscore are internal functions of AccessControl.sol from which I've inherited MyAccessControl contract .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the external one to benefit from the onlyRole check.

In the code you provided, if you call _grantRole() like this, anyone will be able to claim the minter role since you bypass the onlyRole(getRoleAdmin(role)) check that happens in grantRole()

Here is a contract from AAVE github that only uses the external function: https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/1aae831f9c25f6dbfe30770b69fbe74366bdbb32/contracts/protocol/configuration/ACLManager.sol

So you will have to use the external one, that, in turn, will call the internal one.

Hope this helps

Comment: can you refer to my question again , I've added some lines of code .

Comment: AccessControl.sol that I am using is provided by Openzeppelin . See  https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol

Comment: I have edited my answer, let me know if this helps

Comment: Thank you very much . I forgot about the onlyRole() check.

Comment: @OlivierD Can you please explain this line? `This design (i.e. external function doing nothing but calling an internal function) is meant to same gas on function execution, since internal functions use less gas than external ones.`

Comment: @shubhamskatel I just checked for sources and couldn't find any so I wrote some test to see if it was more gas efficient and it actually isn't. I was wrong. No idea why I thought it was true. I removed that line from my comment!

Comment: @OlivierD Yeah, that's what I was thinking, since there will be 2 functional calls, hence more gas fees.

Comment: Then the question is: why would openzeppelin do an external function that calls an internal function like they are doing it in the AccessControl contract? What's the reason for it?

Comment: Internal function can't be called directly. Internal functions from an external function are mostly done to ensure the developer can make any custom changes while importing. Also, if the same code is used in multiple places, this is a good method to avoid redundancy and, in some instances, to reduce contract size.